# fixed header blocking anchor links

Tags: html, css

i have a fixed navigation menu header that is “sticky” as you scroll, chances are you’ve run into this issue. When you click on a link to an anchor further down the page, it scrolls so the anchor is now at the very top of your window…behind the nav header that, of course, has remained at the top of the screen.

i tried to use anchor class but was not able to get it to work

```
 
 ::selection {
  background: #51565D;
}
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}
 
 html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 
.anchor {
display: block;
margin-top: 7%;
visibility: hidden;
}
  
#projects, #products, #contact, #volunteer {
 font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 }

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.img {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. It's very difficult for us to help without some HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend adding a padding to the top of the anchor element, that is the same size as the height of the sticky element (pushing the contents into view)

For example (and just a guess) maybe you could change

margin-top: 7%;
to
padding-top: 7%

Answer (score -1):

Found it:

```
.anchor:target {
  padding-top: 60px;
  scroll-margin-top: 60px;
}

#projects,
#products,
#contact,
#volunteer {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  scroll-margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation, not just a code dump. We'd have to compare this and the original line by line to see what you changed. Please see [answer].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).